# Can't install Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can not install Laravel. I am using xampp. [here's what I get when I try and install it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO3pW.png)

Comment: Have you even read the error message? 

You are trying to create a laravel application named blog, but the directory 'blog' already exists

Comment: First of all Laravel is not a plugin, its a PHP framework.Create a new folder in xampp>htdocs then install Laravel framework with this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3 .If you have installed composer then you can do with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blogName` in your command shell (run command shell into htdocs folder).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a Laravel application under the name `Blog`:

```
rm blog -r
laravel new blog
```

If you want to create a Laravel application under different name:

```
laravel new applicationname
```

(I assume you're very new to Laravel, so welcome! You can delete this question if you want to so it won't hurt your reputation, I'm already give it one thumbs up so it won't hurt that much :) )

Answer (score 0):

The message says that the Laravel project is already created. If you want to create a new Laravel project you have to delete it first, or create it with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is designed to be installed into a fresh project directory. However, if for some reason you want to install Laravel into an existing non-empty directory, do the following.

In this example, we install Laravel into `foo` and then copy it into an existing project named `bar`

1) Create the new Laravel project:

```
$ laravel new foo
```

You should now see your two projects:

```
$ ls
foo/      bar/
```

2) Copy Laravel project files into `bar/` and rerun Composer installation.

```
rsync -av --ignore-existing --exclude=vendor foo/ bar
cd bar/
composer install
```

Beware that this will not overwrite any files in case of name conflicts. If you have an existing `composer.json`, you will need to manually `composer require` all the Laravel dependencies. Similarly, if you have an existing .gitignore file, then you should manually merge the two.